# Cannot set Traffic mode in SKMaps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, traffic, skmaps

I have downloaded the skmap android sdk and demo project from [this](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download). This sktools.jar doesnot have setTrafficMode. I downloaded the latest jar, but yet the method is not found. How can I get the method in my skMapsettings class?

[Here](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/index.html?index-all.html), the documentation clearly shows the method and in [this](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec032) there is the use of the mentioned method which i am unable to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traffic API is available only in the enterprise build. While the documentation is publicly available, for receiving access to the enterprise build you will need to contact the skobbler/Telenav team (dev(at)telenav.com)

Comment: Hey  I am also using SKMaps. My app is running on Nexus 9 but it crashes on all other devices.  here is my question [my question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389919/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-fault-addr-0x4-in-tid-15323-glthread-2978)